Aggrid displaying value of type array seperated by newlines
We recently moved to Agrid.
I'm getting an error displaying a value of type array.
This is the data:
[
{"doorlooptijd": 9,"email": ["m.smith@somewhere.nl"]},
{"doorlooptijd": 105, "email": ["p.puk@somewhere.nl","j.doe@somewhere.nl"}
]

As you can see the second records email is an array containing 2 values.
I want to display these values seperated by a new line.
I succeeded this with the following columnDefs:
columnDefs[
            {field: "doorlooptijd", headerName: "Doorlooptijd", width: 75},
            {field: "email", headerName: "EMail", width: 200, autoHeight: true, cellRenderer: params => params.value === null ? '' : params.data.upn.join('<br>')}
            ]

Although everything is displayed nicely and I can even filter on the individual email entries m.smith, p.puk and j.doe but I get the following javascript error:

AG Grid: Cell data type is "object" but no value formatter has been provided. Please either provide an object data type definition with a value formatter, or set "colDef.valueFormatter"

When I replace the renderer by the valueFormatter (with the array join code) I don't get the error but  all the values are shown on a single line.
What I'm I doing wrong?
